# LibreOffice - Replacing specific parts of a text line

Tags: formatting, libreoffice

I have a series of lines in LibreOffice/OpenOffice, formatted like so:

```
title(tab)data1(tab)data2(tab)data3
```

(tab) is an actual tab character.

What I would like to be able to do is:

1. prepend the line with "____ "
2. bold "title"
3. remove the first (tab), and surround data1 with brackets []
4. change the second (tab) to ": "
5. remove the third tab, and surround data3 with brackets []

The lines would hopefully end up as:
    ____ title [data1]: data2 [data3]

How can this happen?

Comment: LibreOffice and OpenOffice are office suites containing multiple applications. So where you have the text lines? In Calc, in Writer, in ...? Why multiple seach and replace actions will not suit? What have you tried? Why is it failed? And at last, with which programming language you want solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit -> Find and Replace`:

1. Enter in the "Search For" box: `^([a-z0-9 ]+)\t([a-z0-9 ]+)\t([a-z0-9 ]+)\t([a-z0-9 ]+)$`.  Adjust this expression if the titles or data contain other characters such as punctuation.  [Documentation is here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions).
2. Enter in the "Replace With" box: `____ $1 [$2]: $3 [$4]`
3. Expand "Other Options" and check `Regular expressions`.
4. Press `Replace All` to perform the replacement.

[image: replace text]

Then, bold the title as follows:

5. Search for: `(?<=____)([a-z0-9 ]+) (?=\[)`
6. Press the `Find All` button and close the dialog.

[image: find titles]

Now all the titles should be selected.  Press the button in the toolbar to bold the text.

Comment: Wow!  I haven't had a chance to get back to this, but I will try it as soon as I can.